# Find an optimal solution for $\min_{x} F(x)$ analytically

Tags: calculus, convex-optimization

I want to find an analytical solution (exact/closed-form) for $x$ of the following minimization problem:
$$\min_{x} b x \left[e^\left(\frac{a}{x}\right)-1\right]+d (1-c-x) \left[e^ \left(\frac{a}{1-c-x}\right)-1\right]$$ where $0\leq c+x\leq 1$ and $c,x\geq0$. It can be shown that the above minimization function, say $F(x)$, has a minimum because of $\frac{d^2F(x)}{dx^2}>0$. Therefore, I tried to find $x$ by solving $\frac{dF(x)}{dx}=0$, but it is complicated as I cannot write $x$ in terms of other variables. Here is the expression which I find

$$\frac{dF(x)}{dx}=b \left[e^{a/x} \left(1-\frac{a}{x}\right)-1\right]-\frac{d e^{-\frac{a}{c+x-1}} (a+c+x-1)}{c+x-1}+d=0.$$

Can some one help me to solve this equation for $x$?

Otherwise, can someone suggest me an alternative way to find $x$?

Comment: Since there are constraints on $x$, you need to write down the Lagrangian. But in general there is no closed form.

Comment: I don't think you need to go so far as to build a Lagrangian. It's strictly convex, so you can just check the boundary points and the unconstrained minimum. I agree however that you're not going to find a closed-form solution. Why would you assume that you can?